# Using free() for char-pointer in struct

Tags: c, struct, malloc, char-pointer

```
typedef struct inventory 
{
   char *name; 
   int quantity; 
   double price; 
   struct inventory* next_inventory; 
   
} invent;

int main(void)
{
   invent *one=malloc(sizeof(invent)); 
   invent *two=malloc(sizeof(invent));
   invent *three=malloc(sizeof(invent));

   one->next_inventory=two;
   two->next_inventory=three;
   three->next_inventory=NULL;

   one->name=malloc(256);
   ...(repeat two->name, three->name)
   
   printf("name: ");
   scanf("%s", one->name);

   printf("qunatity: ");
   scanf("%d", &one->quantity);

   printf("price: ");
   scanf("%lf", &one->price);
   
   ...(repeat scanf() for two, three)

   while(one!=NULL)
   {
      printf("%s %d %.0f\n", one->name, one->quantity, one->price);
      printf("check\n");
      one=one->next_inventory;
   }

   free(one->name);
   free(two->name);
   free(three->name);
   free(one);
   free(two);
   free(three);

   return 0;
```

free(one->name); doesn't work. I checked another free(), using printf("check");, two->name, three->name, one ... its worked. Why only free(one->name) doesn't work? What can I do for solve this problem? Give me the advice.

Comment: `free(one->name); doesn't work` What do you mean by "doesn't work"? How _exactly_ do you see that that statement "doesn't work"?

Comment: Well `one` is NULL at that point. I know it's NULL because if it wasn't NULL then the loop would've kept looping.

Comment: @KamilCuk Segmentation fault: 11. And program is shut down.

Comment: @user253751 Then what can I do for this problem? I should return the memory I used.(using malloc)

Comment: try using a temporary variable to iterate.

Comment: @erehwyrevemai Why would you want to `free()` a NULL pointer?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio one->name and one is only NULL pointer? or is there another NULL pointer?

Comment: You could not set one to NULL. Use a different variable for the loop.

Comment: @user253751 I can't use a different variable. Because "There are only `one, two, three pointer` to point to struct." It's condition to my homework.

Comment: @user3121023 It's work!!! Thank you very much...really really thank you...user 3121023!!!!!

Comment: what if you have 100 elements in the inventory ? you go on doing one->next_inventory->next_inventory...100times...->name ?

Comment: @farbiondriven If I have 100 elements in the inventory, of course I using loop(one=one->next_inventory). But In this homework , I can't use temporary pointer(condition), and there is only three struct(one, two, three, it's also condition). So In this case, `one->next_inventory->next_inventory->name` was the best way. If my homework wasn't conditional, I would have followed your advice! I really appreciate your comment!

Comment: @user3121023 It's good way, but it doesn't match the conditions. I choice `one->next_inventory->next_inventory->name`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are using your actual 'one' variable to do the iteration, in the end you are trying to `free(one)` where one points to NULL.

You should not lose track of the address of the memory you requested to allocate, to be able to release that memory later with `free`.

I would use a temporary pointer to iterate:

```
 invent* tmp = one;
 while(tmp!=NULL)
   {
      printf("%s %d %.0f\n", tmp->name, tmp->quantity, tmp->price);
      printf("check\n");
      tmp=tmp->next_inventory;
   }

// free all names and one, two, three.
```

In alternative:

you can define a function for printing:

```
void printAll(invent* one)
{
    while(one!=NULL)
   {
      printf("%s %d %.0f\n", one->name, one->quantity, one->price);
      one=one->next_inventory;
   }
}
```

then in the main, call

```
printAll(one)
```

This works as the pointer is passed by value in the function and you won't lose the original address.

Comment: It's my homework, so it has conditions. Struct must have char *name, don't make struct without struct one, two, three, only using struct one for print. I appreciate your advice,  But I can't using temporary pointer.

Comment: you can't iterate using `one`, because how would you know after you are done with the printing where `one` was originally pointing to ?

Comment: My professor said "There are only `one, two, three pointer` to point to struct. So I can't use `temporary pointer`. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a improved version of your program that includes also checking `malloc` return code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct invent 
{
   char *name; 
   int quantity; 
   double price; 
   struct invent* next_inventory; 
   
} invent;

void enter(invent **s)
{
   printf("name: ");
   scanf("%s", (*s)->name);

   printf("quantity: ");
   scanf("%d", &(*s)->quantity);

   printf("price: ");
   scanf("%lf", &(*s)->price);
   
}

void *alloc(size_t size)
{
    void *p;
    
    p = malloc(size);
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(1);
    }
    return p;
}

int main(void)
{
   invent *start;

   invent *one;
   invent *two;
   invent  *three;

   one = alloc(sizeof(invent)); 
   two = alloc(sizeof(invent));
   three = alloc(sizeof(invent));

   start = one;

   one->next_inventory=two;
   two->next_inventory=three;
   three->next_inventory=NULL;

   one->name=alloc(256);
   two->name=alloc(256);
   three->name=alloc(256);


   enter(&one);
   enter(&two);
   enter(&three);

   while(one != NULL)
   {
      printf("%s %d %.0f\n", one->name, one->quantity, one->price);
      printf("check\n");
      one=one->next_inventory;
   }

   free(start->name);
   free(two->name);
   free(three->name);
   free(start);
   free(two);
   free(three);

   return 0;

}
```

Comment: I appreciate your advice, pifor. But  my professor said "There are only `one, two, three pointer` to point to struct. What  should I do without using `start`?

Comment: Please give *all* specifications that you have: do you really need to have a loop to print data ? Do you really need to free memory ? Is C structure mandatory ? Can we modify this structure ? etc. This homework looks a little bit too artificial ...

Comment: I solved problem. Thank you pifor!!! When I think about it, I don't need to have a loop to print data.